# How to XOR a hex string with a literal string in Python?

Tags: python, encryption, unicode, hex, encode

My ultimate goal is to encrypt/decrypt a string with a hex string using a linear congruence generator.

I have a list of 'keys' that I want to XOR with a string. For example, the list of keys are `['0x92', '0xe3', 0x18'...]` and the string I want to XOR with the keys is `'apple'`. The length of the keys list is the same length of the string.

I want to be able to produce a result such as `"\xF3\x93\x68..."`.

I'm not sure how to begin this approach. Should I turn every character in the string to binary and also turn each hex string in binary and XOR them together?

The result that I am looking for (xF3..), is that unicode?

Comment: What do you mean "turn into binary"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the length of the `keys` is equal to the length of the `text` can simply use a `zip` and use a `join` to generate a string:

```
keys = ['\x92', '\xe3', '\x18']
text = 'app'
result = ''.join(chr(ord(key)^ord(tex)) for key,tex in zip(keys,text))
```

The code works as follows: `zip` emits tuples of elements in `keys` and `text`: so the result of `zip(keys,text)` is roughly:

```
list(zip(keys,text)) == [('\x92', 'a'), ('ã', 'p'), ('\x18', 'p')]
```

Now we unify `key` and `tex` with each of these tuples, so in the first iteration `key` is `'\x92'` and `tex` is `'a'`. By calling `ord(..)` on these elements, we obtain the ASCII code. Next we perform a XOR (`^`) operation on these ASCII codes and convert this back to the corresponding `char(..)`. We use `''.join(..)` to concatenate all these characters together into the resulting string, which is:

```
result == 'ó\x93h'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ord` and `chr`

```
>>> a = 0x22
>>> a
34
>>> b = ord('Z')
>>> b
90
>>> a^b
120
>>> chr(a^b)
'x'
```